# Recreate directory structure when extracting from zip file

Tags: java, zip

I need to extract a zip file using java code.
Using java.util.zip, I am unable to extract files in the exact directory structure as inside a zip file, I keep getting IOException: Parent of file is not a directory, please advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is some solution: [How should I extract compressed folders in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/938958/how-should-i-extract-compressed-folders-in-java/939060#939060)

Answer (score 0):

Create the appropriate directory before attempting to extract the file.